# Vue computed syntax error with mapState

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have this code:

```
 computed: {
      mapState(["appErrors", "user", "profilesFor"]),
      compiledData () {
      return {
        template: `<p>${this.data}</p>`
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically I am using Vuex and it has mapState but I also want to define my own computed functions so I changed

`computed: mapState(["appErrors", "user", "profilesFor"])` --**Works**

to

```
computed: {
      mapState(["appErrors", "user", "profilesFor"]),
      compiledData () {
      return {
        template: `<p>${this.data}</p>`
      }
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work. How would I fix this issue?

Comment: Ah, we meet again Tim.  Try `...mapState(["appErrors", "user", "profilesFor"]), `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`mapState` helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) provides an object containing computed getter functions.

Use the [spread operator](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) to include each of those functions in your `computed` object:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(["appErrors", "user", "profilesFor"]),
  compiledData () {
    return {
      template: `<p>${this.data}</p>`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 3 milliseconds :)

Comment: @Bert whoops typo, getter not generator